# naive bayes classifier error in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I use [`naiveBayes e1071`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Classification/Na%C3%AFve_Bayes) for classifying my data set (Classification class: "V32" 0/1).

Here is what I do:

```
    d <- read.table("Modeling_Data.txt",header=FALSE,sep="\t",
                    comment.char="",quote="")
    #divide into training and test data 70:30
    trainingIndex <- createDataPartition(d$V32, p=.7, list=F)
    d.training <- d[trainingIndex,]
    d.testing <- d[-trainingIndex,]
    nb.classifier <- naiveBayes(as.factor(d$V32) ~ ., data = d.training)
```

But I get this error:

```
    Error in names(dimnames(tables[[i]])) <- c(Yname, colnames(x)[i]) : 
    attempt to set an attribute on NULL
    predict(nb.classifier,d.testing[,-50000])
    Error in predict(nb.classifier, d.testing[, -50000]) : 
    object 'nb.classifier' not found
```

I tried to use the included the data set (iris) and everything works fine. What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like building of the model failing (and as a result the classifier is not constructed). Without looking at your data, my best guess would be that you have incomplete cases.

You could try removing cases with missing data using `complete.cases` as follows.

```
d <- read.table("Modeling_Data.txt",header=FALSE,sep="\t",comment.char="",quote="")

# remove incomplete cases
d[complete.cases(d),]

# divide into training and test data 70:30
trainingIndex <- createDataPartition(d$V32, p=.7, list=F)
```